# Using a UsersController with Casein gem - super mismatch for class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-3-upgrade

I am upgrading an app to Rails 3 which has meant upgrading the gems as well. I upgraded the gem Casein but now I can't get my tests to run because there is now a conflict with my UsersController, as Casein also has a UsersController (https://github.com/spoiledmilk/casein3/blob/master/app/controllers/casein/users_controller.rb) so I get this error:

```
superclass mismatch for class UsersController (TypeError)
```

I know this means I have to rename my UsersController (and therefore the User model as well?) but I don't know the best way to do this...

I was playing around with the idea of just changing the name of the controller (and file as well) to include an extra 's', i.e. UserssController

But I think there must be a better way to avoid this clash?!

If this is the only way to do it, do I also need to change the name of the User table in the database or will it still be ok? - If I do need to change it, how do I go about it?